# Auto confirm users in Elgg

Tags: php, elgg

I have been working with [Elgg](http://elgg.org). An open source social networking software created in php. I have been working with the API and so far have been able to register users using the register_user function:

```
register_user($username, $password, $email);
```

The problem however is that I don't need users to confirm via emails when registered through the API. I need to know which function I could use to 'auto confirm' the user.

Comment: They don't mention this functionality in the [Elgg API](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Main_Page)?

Comment: I've been browsing the site. I still am. There are a lot of functions but if someone has any knowledge of what to use then it could be useful.

Comment: What version of Elgg are you working in?  1.7.x or 1.8.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in Elgg 1.8 (might also work in 1.7), and you have the uservalidationbyemail plugin enabled, I think the easiest thing to do would be to disable that plugin.  If you still want to have some of the functionality of the plugin, just not that one part, you could use elgg_unregister_plugin_hook_handler to keep uservalidationbyemail_disable_new_user() from being called, like:
    elgg_unregister_plugin_hook_handler('register', 'user', uservalidationbyemail_disable_new_user');

Alternatively, if you want it to work on some users, but not on ones that register a particular way, then you could add your own plugin hook handler with a lower priority number, and short circuit the default handling:
elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('register', 'user', my_registration_function', 1);

Comment: ok I disabled the uservalidationbyemail plugin. However, users that were register by the function `register_user ()` doesn't seem to work. I tried logging in to the site using the username and passwords of users I created and none of them work.

Comment: Somehow, register_user isn't inserting metadata in the elgg_metadata table. It blocks logging in of users create via register_user function.

Comment: The users won't get inserted to the metadata table. Check the elgg_users_entity table. If the users are not there, it seems you are having some error in your code.